# FactoryBot sequence with parameter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sequence, factory-bot

I want to be able to increment different codes in the same manner. For example:

- If the code is `1234`: `1234, 1234A, 1234B, ...`
- If the code is `5678`: `5678, 5678A, 5678B, ...`

It would be nice if I could get it to skip the first iteration somehow, but my main concern is somehow being able to pass a different `code` for the sequence to use so I don't have to create a different sequence for each code.

```rb
# Not ideal
FactoryBot.define do
  sequence(:1234, "A") { |n| "1234" + n }
  sequence(:5678, "A") { |n| "5678" + n }
end
```

I tried using a factory that calls a sequence, but I can't find any examples of using a factory that creates a string.

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  sequence(:letter, "A") { |n| n }

  factory :violation_code, :class => "String" do
    transient do
      code { "" }
    end
    base_code { code + generate(:letter) }
  end
end

build(:violation_code, :code => "1234")
```

I get this error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'base_code=' for "":String`.

Requirements:

- Generates string with code and incremented letter.

Would be nice:

- Skips first iteration so it returns just the code on the first call to `generate()`.
- When it gets to `Z`, would like it to go to `AA` instead of `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have to create a different sequence for each code

This is obviously impossible because of `FactoryBot` stores the *iterator* and calls [`#next`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/lib/factory_bot/sequence.rb#L21) under the hood. You cannot share the iterator between sequences.

What you can do, you can start directly with `"1234A"`:

```
"1234A".next
#⇒ "1234B"
```

Unfortunately, it goes to `"1235A"` from `"1234Z"`. But `"Z".next` produces `"AA"`. So, wrap the `FactoryBot::DefinitionProxy#sequence` into:

```
FactoryBot::DefinitionProxy.prepend(Module.new do
  def sequence(name, *args, &block)
    if args.last.is_a?(Hash) && prefix = args.last.delete(:prefix)
      super(name, *args) { |n| prefix + n }
    else
      super
    end
  end
end)
```

and call it like:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  sequence("A", prefix: "1234")
end
```

I did not test it, and it surely might be significantly improved, but the idea should be clear.

Comment: Very interesting! Will this change the definition for all sequences to allow a block as a third argument?